# How to run python module in Windows

Tags: python

I need to run this in Windows Power Shell or command line

```
poker_ai.terminal.runner --agent offline --pickle_dir ./research/blueprint_algo --strategy_path ./research/blueprint_algo/offline_strategy_285800.gz --debug_quick_start
```

but dont know how to change the "--" and where "()" is required.

I can see poker_ai.terminal.runner is imported as a module.

I am trying something like this and get the error followed

> > > poker_ai.terminal.runner('agent="offline"')
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Are you running this in a command shell or inside a Python REPL? In the former, you can't use module-qualified names, since the shell doesn't understand them. In the latter, you can't use `--agent`-style command line flags, since Python will try to evaluate them.

Comment: Thanks Silvio. from what you say I understand I cant run in either? when running from Python Idle it cant find the modules such as rich etc. So I wouldnt know how to run there

Comment: `python -m poker_ai.terminal.runner --agent offline ...`

Answer (score 0):

I could run this from Windows Power Shell:

```
python -m poker_ai.terminal.runner --agent offline --pickle_dir ./research/blueprint_algo --strategy_path ./research/blueprint_algo/offline_strategy_285800.gz --debug_quick_start
```